# Problem with the dropping package?

Tags: packages, drop-cap

I have a problem using the `dropping` package. It says that the file `dropping.sty` is not found.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Is there another package, instead of the `dropping` one, performs the same task as the `dropping` package?

Answer (score 10):

As said at [this CTAN site](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dropping):

> Package dropping: Drop first letter of paragraphs.
>
> The package provides A LaTeX2e macro for dropping the first character(s) (or word(s)) of a paragraph, extending the LaTeX 2.09 package [dropcaps](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dropcaps) and automatically taking care of finding the font name. Now largely superseded by [lettrine](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lettrine).